# find the record that holds the foreign key

Tags: sql, join

Let's say I have two tables, Product and Sale, Sale holds a foreign key to Product, so it's a one-to-many relationship with Product as one and Sale as many. How to write sql to get the Product of a Sale?

Answer (score 2):

[`JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) the two tables:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM Product AS p
INNER JOIN Sale AS s ON s.ProductId = p.ProductId
WHERE s.SaleId = ...
```

Then you can specify a `WHERE` clause to filter on the `Sale` table, and `SELECT` whatever columns you want to select from the two tables.

You probably  might need to have a look at the different types of `JOIN`s:

- [**A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).